# AngularJS: error: expected undefined to be defined

Tags: angularjs

I am getting error : Expecting undefined to be defined. When i try on Visual Studio its working fine, but not on the test site that i am working on.
**HTML Code :**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="lib/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angularjs/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="number1"><br><br>
<input type="number" ng-model="number2"><br><br>
{{number1}} + {{number2}} = <span style="color:green" type="text">{{number1 + number2}}</span> which is an
<span ng-bind="odd_even(number1 + number2)"></span> number
<br><br>
{{number1}} - {{number2}} = <span style="color:green" type="text">{{number1 - number2}}</span> which is 
<span ng-bind="odd_even(number1 + number2)"></span> number
<br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller JS Code :**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        //add your code here
        $scope.odd_even = function(result) {
            if(result % 2 == 0) {
                return 'even';
}
            else if(result % 2 == 1){
                return 'odd';
            }
        }
    });
```

**Error :**

```
AngularJS Test Controller: Testing: Check the scope object number1 is defined or not FAILED                   
        Expected undefined to be defined.                                                                                                   
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/index_test.js:19:36)                                                                           
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.9.4) AngularJS Test Controller: Testing: Check the scope object number2 is defined or not FAILED                   
        Expected undefined to be defined.
```

Please help !!!

Comment: Right up front I'll admit I'm not familiar with how `angular-mocks` works for testing, but neither `number1` nor `number2` are defined on `$scope` in the controller. Is that perhaps a requirement for the testing harness to work properly?

Comment: Yes, thats right. Can you please help me with the same.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try like this and let me know if any issues?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    //add your code here
    $scope.number1 = 100;
    $scope.number2 = 11;

    $scope.result = $scope.number1+$scope.number2;

    $scope.odd_even = function(result)
    {

        if(result%2==0)
        {
            return "even";
        }
        else if(result % 2 == 1)
        {
            return "odd";
        }
    }
});
```